# Issues with checking number of channels in a channel category

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm wanting to check for more than 1 channel is a specific discord category. However I'm getting the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')` on the line `if(category.children.size > 1)`

I'm usinng discord.js V14.8.0

Here is my code:

```
const category = interaction.channel.parentId === "864617007025069057"

    if(category.children.size > 1) {
        interaction.reply("Modmail category has more than one channel")
    }
```

I tried this line of code and was expecting it to reply with the interaction reply.

Comment: `interaction.channel.parentId === "864617007025069057"` is a boolean and that has no `children` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your category object isn't a channel object.

If your category has an id of `864617007025069057`, you can get it with:

```js
const category = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("864617007025069057");

if(category.children.size > 1) {
    interaction.reply("Modmail category has more than one channel")
}
```